# Truffle migrate : Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: ethereum, truffle

When i run "truffle migrate" i'm getting the following error:

```
var HelloWorld=artifacts.require(“HelloWorld”);
                                 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at Object.createScript (vm.js:246:10)
```

I'm using a MacOs.

Any suggestions on why this problem is occuring?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. As The char “ is similar to ", i didn't see it was there so i had to replace it to the " char in order to work. So i replaced:

```
var HelloWorld=artifacts.require(“HelloWorld”);
```

with

```
var HelloWorld=artifacts.require("HelloWorld");
```

Comment: thats a really stupid common catch, but yeah. My error was way non explicit compared to yours. But it was the same cpoy/paste mistake I had already fixed elsewhere